# How auth0 builds SAML auth request in Lock js

Tags: javascript, saml, saml-2.0, auth0, auth0-lock

I want to build SAML request in JavaScript. I've seen Auth0 lock.js building the url on the fly when configured email domain is entered, i.e.: outlook.com.

The code is open source but is written in React which I'm not so good with.

GitHub > **https://github.com/auth0/lock**

Lock.js file on cdn: **https://cdn.auth0.com/js/lock/11.11/lock.js**

Can anyone please help me understand the process/tools used here to build the SAML request?

My goal is to build SAMLRequest in JavaScript, if you know other tools, please let me know.

TIA

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are thinking of using Auth0, the code is not in Lock.

It's inside Auth0 itself where you have configured a SAML connection.

Probably the closest is Passport SAML written in node.js.